# Android onResume before onDetachedFromWindow

Tags: android

Hi i use onDetachedFromWindow to save the stance of some Controlls in the shared preferences.

I have an Other activity which resets all stances in its onResume function.

But it seems that onResume of the new activity is called before onDetachedFromWindow from the old activity.

So the controlls save their stance after the reset, and the reset is ineffective.

Can anyone explain why android does so and can suggest alternatives for OnResume or onDetachedFromWindow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be a normal behavior. Previos Activity may detach after onResume of the new Activity
To overcome this issue you can save the state at

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```